# Use of article with the word "future" - another example!

Tags: articles

A few months ago, there was a post asking when one must use an article like "the" or "a/an" with the word "future." The discussion focused on determining whether "future" is being used as a noun or a noun adjunct (functioning as an adjective). The answers made sense to my brain and my ear.

Here, however, is a slight twist: my school uses the phrase "Building Jewish Future" constantly, and it sounds wrong to me (I'd probably say "Building a Jewish Future" or "Building Judaism's Future"). Is "Building Jewish Future" correct or incorrect, and why so?

Many thanks.

Comment: It sounds unusual to me, too. It seems as though the school is using "future" as a mass noun, but I think that most people will interpret it as referring to a particular future (a Jewish one) and therefore consider it to be a count noun, requiring a determiner.

Comment: It's advertising, and one of the things advertisers do is violate rules to get your attention, like a blinking light. All they can get is your attention, after all.

Comment: Slogans also often violate grammar rules. Like advertising tag lines, they tend to be short and punchy.

Comment: To me it sounds like we're talking with [sic] Russian accent.